# Bash script to check if output of cmd increases over a period of time and if so run

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking to compare the output of a file in between time-frames. 
Example:
Run command and it outputs a numerical value 1 to 1000 (1-1000). I need to run the same command 15 min later and see if it has increased by 20 and if so send email.

I am thinking this is very simple, however I cannot get my head around where to even start.

I would think that I would have to run the command and output to file and when the command runs again in 15 min compare those values. I would think that I would need to check if the output file exists and then create if not.

I am new to scripting and could use the help. I got the below but just am stuck beyond. I am looking to make this as simple as possible

```
#!/bin/bash

today="date '+%Y_%m_%d'"
command="echo "select count(status) from alarm where status ='open'" | my-db"
# the command above will return the following for example
#count(status)
#34

$command > /tmp/$today.dblogout
```

Comment: You don’t seem to be running ‘command’. You may want to look up ‘command substitution’ (the ‘$( ... )’ constructs) the answers use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply keep the last known (last retrieved) value in a temporary file, and every time the script is executed, check for how much the value has increased since last run (updating the last known value along the way).

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
store=/tmp/last_value
threshold=20

last=$(<"$store")
current=$(my-db <<<"select count(status) from alarm where status = 'open'" | tee "$store")

if (( current - last > threshold )); then
    echo "Sending mail..."
fi
```

Comment: Does the state need to be kept between reboots? If so, another idea would be a dot-file out of /tmp.

Comment: @Guy, exactly, last value file doesn't have to reside in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

I made something similar to alert me if my disk is getting full:

```
#!/bin/sh

THRESHOLD=85

datafile=/var/run/df_slash_var_pcent_avail.txt

# get previous value:
prev=$(tail -1 $datafile | cut -d\  -f2)

# get current value
curr=$(($(df /var --output=pcent | tail -1 | cut -d% -f1) + 0))

# store current value
echo "$(date +%s) $curr" >> $datafile

# if getting worse, alert
[[ $curr > $THRESHOLD ]] && [[ $curr > $prev ]] && smsme "/var grew from ${prev}% to ${curr}%"
```

This script is pretty straightforward. Feel free to ask if sth is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options

- If alerts table has a date column you can write an SQL query to get the count for you.
- Use bash to get the values

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # Store date in a variable, note the $( ) surrounding the command
  today="$(date '+%Y_%m_%d')"
  old=0

  # read the old value from file if it exists
  if [ -f /tmp/$today.dblogout ]; then
      old="$(< /tmp/$today.dblogout)"
  fi

  # store just the value without any header
  new=$(echo "select count(status) from alarm where status ='open'" | my-db)
  # the command above will return the following for example
  #34

  # response is not empty
  if [ -z "$new" ]; then
      echo "old count: $old, new count: $new"
  else
      echo "new value is empty. old value: $old"
  fi

  # store the new value
  echo "$new" > /tmp/$today.dblogout
  ```